# Prevent TeamCity reporting ReSharper Code Inspection Suggestions (and Hints) as Warnings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper-7.1, teamcity-8.0, code-inspection

I have added an Inspections (.NET) build step to a TeamCity (v8) project consisting of a Visual Studio 2010 solution build step for a single dummy C# class.

The build step has failure conditions that are set to fail if I get any inspection Errors or Warnings.

My dummy class only generates 2 Suggestions but the build fails claiming

> "Build failure on metric change: Number of inspection warnings is too
>   large: 3".

Is there a way to make the TeamCity step ignore the Suggestions?

I enabled debug output and the step definitely has no Warnings in it:

```
<!-- Generated by InspectCode 2.0.0.0 -->
<Report ToolsVersion="2.0">
<Information>
 <Solution>Demo.sln</Solution>
 <InspectionScope><Element>Solution</Element></InspectionScope>
</Information>
<IssueTypes><IssueType Id="InconsistentNaming" Category="Constraints Violations" Description="Inconsistent Naming" Severity="SUGGESTION"/>
 <IssueType Id="UnusedMember.Global" Category="Redundancies in Symbol Declarations" Description="Type or type member is never used: Non-private accessibility" Severity="SUGGESTION"/>
</IssueTypes>
<Issues>
 <Project Name="Demo">
  <Issue TypeId="UnusedMember.Global" File="Demo\Class1.cs" Offset="36-42" Line="3" Message="Class 'Class1' is never used"/>
  <Issue TypeId="UnusedMember.Global" File="Demo\Class1.cs" Offset="71-76" Line="5" Message="Field 'maybe' is never used"/>
  <Issue TypeId="InconsistentNaming" File="Demo\Class1.cs" Offset="71-76" Line="5" Message="Name 'maybe' does not match rule 'Fields (not private)'. Suggested name is 'Maybe'."/>
 </Project>
</Issues>
</Report>
```

The dummy class is as follows:

```
namespace Demo
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public bool maybe = true;
    }
}
```

Note that I still want Suggestions and Hints reported in Visual Studio so changing all non-Warnings and Errors to Do Not Report in the ReSharper settings is not an option (or creating and maintaining such a settings file solely for TeamCity to use).

Comment: Nope, but it is on the jetbrains bug tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-30714

Answer (score 6):

Following the [previous suggested technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27510968/260213) I wrote a PowerShell script that runs InspectCode, then performs an XSLT transform of the output file and imports the result into TeamCity. You can run this as a PowerShell build step, passing the solution filename as the first script argument and the variable  %system.teamcity.build.tempDir% as the second.

TransformResults.xslt:

(This should be located in the same folder as the PowerShell script)

```
<xsl:stylesheet
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="issueType" match="IssueTypes/IssueType" use="@Id" />

  <!--
  Template to strip out issues where the severity is HINT or SUGGESTION
  -->
  <xsl:template match="Issues//Issue">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(contains('HINT SUGGESTION', key('issueType', @TypeId)/@Severity))" >
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

RunInspectCode.ps1:

```
param( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$solutionFile, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$buildTempDir)

# Runs the Jetbrains Resharper code inspection utility (InspectCode)
# - see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Introducing+InspectCode
# We don't want to use the built-in TeamCity inspection plugin because it reports
# HINT and SUGGESTION issues, which we don't want to make mandatory.
# Basically we run InspectCode to generate an intermediate XML report, then we 
# transform that report via XSLT to strip out the issues we don't want to see.

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# Required if Powershell < 3.0
#$PSScriptRoot = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

# General-purpose function to transform XML
function Transform-Xml {
    param([string]$stylesheetPath=$(throw '$stylesheetPath is required'),
        [string[]]$xmlPath)

    begin {
        # Compile the stylesheet
        $compiledXslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
        $compiledXslt.Load($stylesheetPath)

        function transformXmlDoc {
            param([xml]$xml, [System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform]$xslt = $(throw '$xslt param is required'))

            $output = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
            $arglist = new-object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList
            $outputReader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($output)

            $xmlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader($xml)
            $xslt.Transform($xmlReader, $arglist, $output)
            $output.position = 0

            $transformed = [string]$outputReader.ReadToEnd()
            $outputReader.Close()
            return $transformed
        }
        function applyStylesheetToXml([xml]$xml) {
            $result = transformXmlDoc $xml $compiledXslt
            [string]::join([environment]::newline, $result)
        }
        function applyStylesheetToXmlFile($sourcePath) {
            $rpath = resolve-path $sourcePath
            [xml]$xml = Get-Content $rpath
            $result = transformXmlDoc $xml $compiledXslt
            [string]::join([environment]::newline, $result)
        }
    }

    process {
        if ($_) {
            if ($_ -is [xml]) {
                applyStylesheetToXml $_
            }
            elseif ($_ -is [IO.FileInfo]) {
                applyStylesheetToXmlFile $_.FullName
            }
            elseif ($_ -is [string]) {
                if (test-path -type Leaf $_) {
                    applyStylesheetToXmlFile $_
                }
                else {
                    applyStylesheetToXml $_
                }
            }
            else {
                throw "Pipeline input type must be one of: [xml], [string] or [IO.FileInfo]"
            }
        }
    }

    end {
        if ($xmlPath) {
            foreach ($path in $xmlPath) {
                applyStylesheetToXmlFile $path
            }
        }
    }
}

$solutionPath = Resolve-Path $solutionFile
$tempDir = Resolve-Path $buildTempDir

# Locate inspectcode
if (-Not (Test-Path Env:\RESHARPER_TOOLS_PATH)) {
    throw 'RESHARPER_TOOLS_PATH environment variable not set'
}

$inspectcode = Join-Path $env:RESHARPER_TOOLS_PATH 'inspectcode.exe'
if (-Not (Test-Path -type Leaf $inspectcode)) {
    throw 'InpectCode executable not found'
}

# Path to XSLT transformation file
$fullXsltPath = Resolve-Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'TransformResults.xslt')

# Names of intermediate and final output files
$intermediateOutput = Join-Path $tempDir 'inspectcode-intermediate.xml'
$outputPath = Join-Path $tempDir 'inspectcode-final.xml'

# Run InspectCode 
& $inspectcode "/o=$intermediateOutput" $solutionPath

# Transform the inspection output to remove HINT and SUGGESTION
$transformed = Transform-Xml $fullXsltPath @($intermediateOutput)

# The PowerShell Out-File cmdlet always adds a UTF8 Byte Order Marker so we need to take steps to
# ensure this is not emitted, as the TeamCity XML importer will choke on it
$encoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($false)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($outputPath, $transformed, $encoding)

# When PowerShell is started through TeamCity's Command Runner, the standard
# output will be wrapped at column 80 (a default). This has a negative impact
# on service messages, as TeamCity quite naturally fails parsing a wrapped
# message. The solution is to set a new, much wider output width. It will
# only be set if TEAMCITY_VERSION exists, i.e., if started by TeamCity.
$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size(8192,50)

Write-Output "##teamcity[importData type='ReSharperInspectCode' path='$outputPath']"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is still not possible with TeamCity 9 (it starts to get embarrassing for JetBrains, as this feature is really a joke without being able to limit only to warnings and errors).

### But there is a do-it-yourself workaround

Using the free [Resharper Command Line Tool "inspectcode"](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html) it is possible to generate an XML report for all Resharper issues:

```
inspectcode.exe /o=codeInspectionReport.xml solution.sln
```

This report still contains **all** issues, but it is then possible to throw an XPath query at the report to count the number of errors and warnings.

Here is how I do it in a Psake build file:

```
Task ReportInspectCode {
  [xml]$xml = Get-Content 'codeInspectionReport.xml'
  $nodes = $xml.selectNodes("/Report/IssueTypes/IssueType[@Severity='ERROR' or (@Severity='WARNING' and @Id!='InconsistentNaming')]")

  if ($nodes.Count -gt 0) {
    Echo $nodes
    throw "There are code inspection errors or warnings, see Resharper -> Inspect -> Code Issues in Solution"
  }
  else {
    Echo "Code inspection completed without warnings or errors"
  }
```

}

As you can see, I also had to filter out spurious `InconsistentNaming` warnings, but you could remove that part if you don't need it.

And you could of course use a similar xpath query in an XSLT transformation to get rid of all non-warnings and non-errors. This way, you could use TeamCity to process the resulting file and display it as code inspection result.

Answer (score 1):

As workaround you can add `--severity=WARNING` argument to inspectCode.exe in InspectCode Options